# Jena - getting a label from an ontology class in any language

Tags: rdf, jena

For user interface purposes I would like to find a label for a given ontology class within Jena.
The label should be in the language preferred by the user, if possible, but if no label is available in the user's language,
I would like to show just any label, and hope the user manages to understand. To do that I would like to loop over all available labels, and then pick one (maybe just the first one for the first attempt).

So far the code looks like:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
public class LabelUtils {
    public static String getLabel(OntClass ontClass, String preferredLanguage) {
        String label = ontClass.getLabel(preferredLanguage);
        if (label == null) {
            // here find another label, in any language, whatever
        }
        return label;
    }
}
```

How do I list all labels, no matter what the language? I only found a method `ontClass.listLabels(String language)` which - of course - only returns labels for that language.

I can just assume that an English label always exist, or loop over a list of hard wired locales that are checked for labels, but that seems really lame.

Comment: "How do I list all labels, no matter what the language? I only found a method ontClass.listLabels(String language) which - of course - only returns labels for that language."  The javadoc for `listLabels` says that if `language` is `null`, then all [labels] are returned.  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are related to elements in OWL through the `rdfs:label` property.

To verify this, we can start with a minimalistic model created through the following means:

```
final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
final OntClass clazz = model.createClass("urn:ex:class");
clazz.addLabel("className1", "en");
clazz.addLabel("className2", "fr");
```

Writing out the model as N3, we get the following content:

```
<urn:ex:class>
      a       owl:Class ;
      rdfs:label "className1"@en , "className2"@fr .
```

Now, because [OntClass](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html) inherits `listPropertyValues` from `OntResource`, we can work with each declared label programmatically like this:

```
final NodeIterator labels = clazz.listPropertyValues(RDFS.label);
while( labels.hasNext() ) {
    final RDFNode labelNode = labels.next();
    final Literal label = labelNode.asLiteral();
    System.out.println( label.getLanguage() );
}
```

For out example application, the following output should hopefully demonstrate that you can reflect on the language tag explicitly.

```
fr
en
```

Comment: This works, but there's a simpler solution using the OntResource listLabels method:  if the lang argument is `null`, then an iterator is returned over all labels.

Comment: I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23092373/1281433) that explains that.

Answer (score 2):

[Rob Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085138/1281433) works, but if you want to use the OntResource interface methods, you can use something closer to your original approach. Note what the Javadoc for [OntResource#listLabels](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#listLabels%28java.lang.String%29) says (emphasis added) the follwing.

> ### [listLabels](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#listLabels%28java.lang.String%29)
>
> > com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator listLabels(String lang)
>
> Answer an iterator over all of the label
>   literals for this resource.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - lang - The language tag to restrict the listed comments to, **or null to select all [labels]**

Comment: So you say I should have read the javadoc. Duh, me! But I see you fixed the typos taking about "comments" instead of "labels" in the javadoc for me :)

Comment: Yes, I did fix the "comments" vs. "labels" bit, but I'm of the opinion that it's a pretty simply copy & paste bug in the doc, given that there's a *very* similar listComments method as well, and the implementation is likely almost exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, I just checked and it works as advertized. Too bad SO does not allow for two "accepted answers". I will send the jena-folks a patch about the typo, anyway ...

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar If you really want to, you can unaccept the currently accepted answer and accept this one, but I do think it's nice that Rob Hall's answer explains how to implement a function like this (which would be helpful if you needed the value of a property other than rdfs:label).

Answer (score 0):

I found this question today, and I thought the [Rob Hall`s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085138/1281433) interesting because, using the method listLabels, you can list only the rdfs: labels. Using that approach, you can list, for example, the labels defined with the vocabulary SKOS (skos: altLabel and skos: prefLabel).

Posting this as an answer because I dont have reputation to comment...